# Intercept spec instance creation in Spockframework

Tags: android, unit-testing, groovy, spock

Is there a way to intercept (or override) object creation different than overriding the whole Sputnik (Spock TestRunner)?

It would be perfect to e.g. create an extension annotation, that changes spec factory:

```
@SpecFactory(SomeFactory)
class MySpec extends Specification {...}
```

The intention behind that is that I need to switch the Classloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec instance construction cannot currently be customized. It would require some thought because instances need to be initialized in a special way. If you are interested in contributing such a feature, I'm happy to discuss it on the [Spock forum](http://forum.spockframework.org).